# In Rails how to schedule a task to check some database values and send reminder emails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need my system to calculate whether a Member's Membership is close to expiring every day and send an email to them. How can I do this?

For example, if I use the Clockwork gem how to do this? Its a bit unclear to me. How can we access the models through the Clockwork? How can we use it with Rails? I think the read me tells how to use it in pure Ruby. Please help. Im new. And how t make sure the scheduler is running?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/)?

You could do something like this:

```
# app/workers/membership_worker.rb
class MembershipWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(account_id)
    account = Account.find(account_id)
    message = "You have #{account.days_remaining}"
    # send reminder email
    # MembershipWorker.perform_in(1.day, account.id)
  end
end

# app/models/membership.rb
after_create ->{ MembershipWorker.perform_in(10.days, self.id) }
```

Comment: Can it be used to schedule tasks?

Comment: You can use [Sidekiq Scheduler](https://github.com/Moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler) for cron-type scheduled tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever)
It allows you to execute rake tasks. U can refer your model from the rake task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clockwork` as long as you include the Rails environment in the configuration file.

For example, you can create a file in your Rails app `config/clock.rb`

```
require_relative 'boot'
require_relative 'environment'
require 'clockwork'

module Clockwork
  every(1.day, 'deliver-email', at: '00:00') {
    YourMailer.email(...).deliver
  }
end
```

This is mentioned in the [QuickStart](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork#quickstart) and [Use with Queueing](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork#use-with-queueing).

Alternatively, you can use the [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever).

I've been using both, but I now then to prefer the `clockwork` approach. Just keep in mind that `clockwork` counts starting from when the process is started. So if you restart the process 10 times, the email will likely to be sent 10 times. Make sure to check the email is not sent multiple times (the way you normally do it is by keeping a delivery log).